# Python get parent classes from another class

Tags: python-3.x, class

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, name, myclass):
        self.name = name
        self.myclass = myclass

   def get_parents(self):
        ? self.myclass.super() ?
        return parent

obj = Art # another class
testobj = Test('testA', obj)
print(testobj.get_parents())
```

The parent class of `Test` can be obtained using `super()`.

How to get the parent classes of `Art` inside `Test` class? (Say `Art` is inherited from `Artists` and `Artists` from `Base`. We need to be able to get `Artists` and `Base` as parents.)

Comment: _"The parent class of Test can be obtained using super()"_ That is not correct. `super` doesn't give you the parent class, it gives you a proxy object.

Comment: Yes. I meant the parent class can be accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the method resolution order with `mro()`:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, name, myclass):
        self.name = name
        self.myclass = myclass

    def get_parents(self):
        return self.myclass.mro()

class Base:
    pass

class Artists(Base):
    pass

class Art(Artists):
    pass

testobj = Test('testA', Art)
print(testobj.get_parents())
```

Output:

```
[<class '__main__.Art'>, <class '__main__.Artists'>, <class '__main__.Base'>, <class 'object'>]
```

This should come close to:

> We need to be able to get `Artists` and `Base` as parents.